# VS2008 Macro: Perform action on every code file in the solution

Tags: visual-studio, macros

I have recently noticed how interesting Visual Studio's macros are. I did not use VB for ages so it took me a while until i finally managed to write a little macro that performs some stuff on the currently open document.

Enthusiastically, I next wanted to use this macro on every source code file (.cs) in the solution without having to manually open all files. Could you give me a quick hint on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [DTE object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa301306(VS.71).aspx) reference. Inside a macro you can reference some really neat global properties, like `DTE.Solution`, which returns a [Solution object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa301150(VS.71).aspx) that describes the currently open solution (and, not surprisingly, has a Projects property, which is a collection of all Projects in the solution). You should be able to iterate over pretty much anything you want at that point!

Have fun :)

Comment: Thanks, missed this. Easier than i thought. :)